# Can I find out the exact edit that awarded me the "I'm Batman" hat?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2015

I just received [I'm Batman](http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/im-batman) hat on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1317053/a%E1%B4%8D%C9%AA%CA%80), but I don't know why. I know what triggers it, but I'm not sure which edit of mine specifically caused it.

Is there any way to find that out?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can see the revisions you made here and click through them.

[https://stackoverflow.com/users/1317053/aᴍɪʀ?tab=activity&sort=revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1317053/a%E1%B4%8D%C9%AA%CA%80?tab=activity&sort=revisions)

Potentially quite tedious but only took a few attempts to find this edit that fits the pattern.

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/34472804/revisions

Comment: Ahh, thanks! Didn't know I can see if a question is re-opened in there.